# call multiple functions when element is dragging

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to perform multiple functions when an element is dragged.I just want to ask how can i call more then one function when an element is drag.This is the code

```
$('#button').draggable(dragOpts);

var dragOpts = {
            start: function01,
            drag: function01
};
```

is this Possible to call two functions at dragging such as

```
var dragOpts = {
            start: function01,
            drag: function01,function02
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to call your 2 functions inside drag event.
here is code

```
var dragOpts = {
            start: function01,
            drag: function(event,ui){
function01(event,ui);
function02(event,ui);
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a function which covers all functions:

```
function myfunc(){
function01();
function02();
}
```

Then call myfunc.

```
var dragOpts = {
            start: function01,
            drag: myfunc
};
```